# Background color disappears for items inside ViewCell in Listview

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a `Listview`, with a custom `ViewCell` that has a bunch of `Frame`s and `Label`s, everything is working fine except that the `BackgroundColor` of all controls inside the `ViewCell` get changed if the parent row is selected.

This only happens in **iOS**.

The following image shows the issue:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: try using CollectionView instead

Comment: Hi, have you sloved this problem ? If got solution , you can share it as an answer, then other people will see it :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT it's an iOS problem, the native control has this bug. It's fixed in iOS 13.

Comment: @Him Okey , got it . If fixed , that's good .